# Django request.user becomes anonymous after changing page. Using custom user model

Tags: python, django

I'm using a custom user model that extends `AbstractBaseUser`. This is the user model:

```
class cUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
    role_id = models.IntegerField()
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    f_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    l_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    address_id = models.IntegerField()
    phone_num = models.IntegerField()
    loan_item_count = models.IntegerField()
    id = models.IntegerField(unique = True, primary_key = True)

    def __init__(self, dictionary, *args, **kwargs):
        self.role_id = int(dictionary['role_id'])
        self.user_id = dictionary['user_id']
        self.email = dictionary['email']
        self.password = dictionary['password']
        self.f_name = dictionary['f_name']
        self.l_name = dictionary['l_name']
        self.address_id = dictionary['address_id']
        self.phone_num = dictionary['phone_num']
        self.loan_item_count = dictionary['loan_item_count']
        self.id = self.user_id

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user_id'
    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

I don't want the model to affect the DB in any way. I'm loading it by a simple raw SQL query from a gateway method.

This is how I'm handling login:

```
def login_request(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = userGateway(username,password)
            if user is not None:
                print("=========USER==========")
                print(user.email)
                user.backend = 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
                login(request,user)
                print(request.user.is_authenticated)
                if user.role_id==1:
                    return render(request, 'biblioteca/admin/landing.html')
                    # return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
                else:
                    return render(request, 'biblioteca/landing.html')
            else:
                print("=========NOT USER==========")
    else:
        if(request.user is not None and not request.user.is_anonymous):
            return render(request, 'biblioteca/admin/landing.html')
        form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'biblioteca/login.html', {'form': form})
```

As you can see, I'm setting the back-end before login to authenticate without having to pass through a password - the password check is being done when the user object is created by comparing the password passed in with the password retrieved from the DB.

If I return a `render`, as seen here, the next page contains the proper request.user object. If I return a redirect, it does not. Additionally, if I leave that page at all, the user becomes unauthenticated and anonymous again, losing the session.

Any help as to why this happens would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why have you overridden the `__init__` function like that? It's an incredibly bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this was solved by turning userGateway() into a proper auth backend and implementing it like that.

Explanation as to why:

The sessionID in django stores a hash of the user's PK as well as the auth backend used to log in. Whenever a new request is sent, data needed is lazy-loaded from the DB using this hash.

This is why login() was properly authenticating the user on the login page, because it was pretty much forced to. As soon as another request happened, though, it would be unable to load the user's data from the DB, and would flush the sessionid.

Comment: So what is the solution for this, i didn't understand

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect, the request is completed and a redirect code is sent to the client, who then makes a new request to the new page without the POST data for the login form. The user may not be getting their token. In that case, render a page to log them in that delays for a few seconds, then redirects them to the right spot.

Comment: As I said, the issue also comes from just changing URLs. If I instead return a render, which does properly maintain the session, and then change the page away from there, the user object is gone again.

Comment: In that case my guess is that something is not being given to identify the user in the request the user makes after changing pages, or it's being given but not handled. Not sure. Sorry!

Comment: The odd thing is that querying request.user gives the expected results after the login(), but any page after that doesn't have it anymore.

Comment: I have the same issue as mr @agsl has